# XML Rename node name and convert datetime to date

Tags: datetime, xslt, element

I have an xml file I want to both rename the  element name and return the date part of the date only to produce

```
<!-- reference the stylesheet -->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Dates.xsl"?>
<user>
<dob>1992-02-22T00:00:00.0000000</dob>
</user>
```

I want to both rename the  element name and return the date part of the date only to produce

```
<!-- reference the stylesheet -->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Dates.xsl"?>
<user>
<USER_DOB>1992-02-22</USER_DOB>
</user>
```

In my XSL file
To change the element name this works

```
  <xsl:template match="dob">
    <USER_DOB><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></USER_DOB>
  </xsl:template>
```

To change the date this works

```
<xsl:template match="dob">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="FormatDate">
            <xsl:with-param name="DateTime" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="FormatDate">

        <xsl:param name="DateTime" />
        <xsl:variable name="date">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($DateTime,'T')" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:if test="string-length($date) != 10">
                <xsl:value-of select="$DateTime"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($date) = 10">
                <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I need to know how to combine both changes to produce the single output element with the renamed node and the formatted date
Thanks,
Brevan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply have one template matching `dob` that does this...

```
<xsl:template match="dob">
    <USER_DOB>
        <xsl:call-template name="FormatDate">
            <xsl:with-param name="DateTime" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>  
    </USER_DOB>
</xsl:template>
```